# Cannot find TLS related ciphers in IBM websphere console

Tags: ssl, websphere, protocols

I have navigated to ***SSL certificate and key management > SSL configurations > NodeDefaultSSLSettings > Quality of protection (QoP) settings*** in the IBM Websphere Console 8.5V and changed the protocol from **SSL_TLS** to **TLS**

Then I have clicked on 'Update selected ciphers" still I could not see any TLS related ciphers below in the "Selected ciphers" list. It only shows SSL related ciphers for example ***SSL_RSA_AES_256*** but **not** something like ***TLS_RSA_AES_256***

Do I have to update to anywhere else to get the TLS related ciphers in websphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL_ is interchangeable with TLS_ in the cipher names.  The IBMJSSE document notes that in the beginning, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.70.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/ciphersuites.html

Even thought the string is saying SSL_RSA_AES_256,  TLS_RSA_AES_256 will be applied.